# not able to use jquery plugins with node

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I was given a node project which was partially made like the initial setup of front-end.

I have been building on top of it but now I require that I use a jQuery plugin like [Sweet Alert Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sweetalert)...

I `npm` installed the sweet-alert with `npm install sweetalert --save`, added it in the head but whenever I am trying to run it in the console its saying the

> `swal` is undefined.

I think i an not adding the jQuery plugins in the right manner into node.

Normally including the script at the top (head) should work fine but for some reason its not working also other js alert substitutes like sweet-modal is also not working.

I have just started development on node kindly help me out..

Comment: you'll have to provide some code samples (mainly of the Html file or a view template you add the script to)  and the folder structure of your project. also,  is it an express Web app? Just saying 'node'  is too broad of a description

Answer (score 0):

This is really good question for the new one in a Node. 
You see, when you do

> npm install sweetalert --save

You just downloaded this js file into your file system. And nothing more. 
And now you should include your script into your page. How can you do this?

For development purpose and if js was build for the browser (I assume yes cause this is jquery plugun) you can add it directly to the page like:

But this is not good way to solve this problem because when you will go to the prod, you will hate yourself.

Another (and better) option is to build a build process and include your script there as a library. How to create a build process? It is too huge theme to discover it here so please, google "gulp" or "webpack".

Hope I help a bit.

Oh, possibly your team already created some build process so try to find out how they includes scripts from npm before.

Comment: there are 2 js files at the end of the page that has a comment written                  * Includes Sizzle.js
 * https://sizzlejs.com/

Comment: check src attribute. May be they use cdn, maybe directly from node, may be they copied files from node to the some folder and included from there.

Comment: The src for other files are coming from an asset folder (which is public) in which I also placed my jquery plugin files....

Comment: then 1. check a console to be sure that script was loaded. 2. check the order to be sure your script is going before your code.

Comment: its very strange..... the plugin files I were putting into the assets/js folder were not working but when I but them on the root public folder they started working.... i don't understand this....

Comment: Then you should check your server mapping. Some folder can be without access or some requests to the resources are redirected to the other folders. Good that it works now.